# Citrix printing - 2 of many thin client workstations cannot print

Tags: printing, citrix

We have a application deployed in a Citrix environment. Many workstations can print to the Citrix print server fine via our application, but 2 cannot (this is limited to our application ie MS Word document prints fine). Of the many workstations, 2 with issues are on the same host as other workstations without issues. There are no printing issues with our application on other workstations. The application is published from the same host. Not having a Citrix background not sure how to go about troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Citrix host (on which users have issues) have the same policies applied comparing to others. In Citrix XenApp 6.0 and higher run **AppCenter** console and inspect policies and **WorkerGroups** they applied on.

Secondly, check Citrix host Windows Event Log for printing errors or printer creation errors.

And lastly check print server for received print jobs and their status.